# Running pip from ~/.local/bin/pip instead of /usr/local/bin/pip

Tags: python, path, pip

I want to install pip 9.0.3 for my local user
and I have changed the pip path

```
$ which -a pip
/efs/home/myuser/.local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ pip install --upgrade pip --user

Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-9.0.3

pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

How do you change which pip is being used?

Comment: pip install --upgrade pip --user -> /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade pip --user   or just cd to /usr/local/bin/pip, then same comand pip install --upgrade pip --user

Comment: The first one gives a permission denied, and the second has the same result as my attempt

Comment: which one do you wanted to use (/efs/home/myuser/.local/bin/pip) or (/usr/local/bin/pip). Just saw the title. for permission issues run like "sudo ~/.local/bin/pip install --upgrade pip --user" it will ask you password

Comment: I want to run /efs/home/myuser/.local/bin/pip as I do not have sudo

Comment: I edited #!/efs/home/myuser/.local/bin/python3.6 in pip. It works, is this the right way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the #! in pip to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
```

After I installed python3.6 in my local dir using a modified version of the instructions available [here](http://thelazylog.com/install-python-as-local-user-on-linux/)^. And added

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin
```

to .bash_profile

```
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.3 from /efs/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

^ The modification was configuring the install

```
./configure --prefix=/efs/home/myuser/.local/
```

and I did not do the 2. Install pip instructions.